# Magical record Saving big amount of data to DB

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I am using magical record to save big amount of data to my database. I want to save it in the background but it freezes the UI. I'm saving it using

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    }];
```

So it should not block the UI. But I've found that it uses main thread for some reasons to merge changes or something like that. I would be really grateful if someone could suggest a solution of how to make this more efficient.

Code that I'm using:

```
- (void)saveRidesForUser:(User *)user fromResponseData:(id)responseData
{

    if (![[[responseData valueForKey:@"rides"] class] isSubclassOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        return;
    }
    NSArray *rides = [responseData valueForKey:@"rides"];

    if (!rides)
        return;

    NSMutableArray *photoCacheArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

        User *rideUser = [user MR_inContext:localContext];

        for (NSDictionary *rideDictionary in rides) {

                Ride *ride = [Ride MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
                ride.title = ([rideDictionary objectForKey:@"title"]) ? [rideDictionary valueForKey:@"title"] : @"";

                NSNumber *rideTimeStamp =[rideDictionary objectForKey:@"start_date"];
                if (rideTimeStamp)
                    ride.startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[rideTimeStamp doubleValue]];

                NSNumber *rideEndTimeStamp =[rideDictionary objectForKey:@"end_date"];
                if (rideEndTimeStamp)
                    ride.endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[rideEndTimeStamp doubleValue]];

                ride.serverID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[rideDictionary objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]];
                ride.isPopular = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];

                if ([rideDictionary objectForKey:@"intervals"]) {
                    NSArray *intervals = [rideDictionary objectForKey:@"intervals"];

                    for (NSDictionary *intervalDictionary in intervals) {

                        RideInterval *interval = [RideInterval MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];

                        interval.startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[intervalDictionary objectForKey:@"start_date"] integerValue]];
                        interval.endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[intervalDictionary objectForKey:@"end_date"] integerValue]];

                        interval.ride = ride;

                        if ([intervalDictionary objectForKey:@"points"] && ![[[intervalDictionary objectForKey:@"points"] class] isSubclassOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                            NSArray *points = [intervalDictionary objectForKey:@"points"];

                            for (NSDictionary *pointDict in points) {

                                NSDictionary *pointDictionary = [pointDict dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings];

                                RidePoint *point = [RidePoint MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
                                point.timestamp = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[pointDictionary objectForKey:@"timestamp"] integerValue]];

                                point.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[pointDictionary objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue]];
                                point.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[pointDictionary objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]];
                                point.distanceFromPrevious = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[pointDictionary objectForKey:@"distance_from_previous"] doubleValue]];
                                point.interval = interval;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ([rideDictionary valueForKey:@"photos"] && [[[rideDictionary valueForKey:@"photos"] class] isSubclassOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                    NSArray *photos = [rideDictionary objectForKey:@"photos"];

                    for (NSDictionary *photoDict in photos) {

                        NSDictionary *photoDictionary = [photoDict dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings];
                        RidePhoto *photo = [RidePhoto MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];

                        photo.caption = [photoDictionary valueForKey:@"caption"];

                        NSNumber *timeStamp =[photoDictionary objectForKey:@"timestamp"];
                        if (timeStamp)
                            photo.timestamp = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[timeStamp doubleValue]];

                        photo.locationLatitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[photoDictionary objectForKey:@"location_latitude"] doubleValue]];
                        photo.locationLongitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[photoDictionary objectForKey:@"location_longitude"] doubleValue]];
                        photo.serverPath = [photoDictionary objectForKey:@"url"];
                        photo.imagePath = [NSString getUUID];
                        photo.ride = ride;

                        [photoCacheArray addObject:photo];
                    }
                }

                ride.user = rideUser;
            }

    } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kLTRideServise_RoutesDownloadedNotification object:nil userInfo:nil];

    }];

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MR_defaultContext for your all other main-thread tasks?

I'm using saveWithBlock: method for background saving, MR_defaultContext for main-thread operations and it works fine. As far as I know, MagicalRecord is merging localContext with defaultContext at the end of saving operation.

Example code:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC),      
dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        // your loop here in background thread
    } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // completion on main thread
        });
    }];
});
```

Comment: yes that's the way I'm doing this. I am saving quite a lot of data, can this be the issue?

Comment: Check when exactly UI starts to freeze - during the 'for' loop, after the loop or after whole saving block.

Comment: the UI freezes right after the for loop. Any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: I've add sample code with GCD for you. This should completely remove freezing from your process.

Comment: unfortunately it is exactly the same. I've read that saveWithBlock shouldn't be used like this. Well anyway I've tried it like that and nothing changed. Any other solution?

Comment: If you could make a sample code and place it on GitHub, I could help you finding a solution. As I told you, I have no trouble with this setup for more than 5000 records saved at one time in background. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kLTRideServise_RoutesDownloadedNotification object:nil userInfo:nil];

==> Check what processing you are doing on completion. This notification is called on main thread, may be you are doing a lot of processing which is keeping main thread busy, resulting in freezing of UI.

Also check if you have registered for NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification from any context, and see if you are doing any processing there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:aCallback];
```

to save context into Database.

It's documented like this

```
/// \brief      Asynchronously save changes in the current context all the way back to the persistent store
/// \param       completion  Completion block that is called after the save has completed. The block is passed a success state as a `BOOL` and an `NSError` instance if an error occurs. Always called on the main queue.
/// \discussion Executes asynchronous saves on the current context, and any ancestors, until the changes have been persisted to the assigned persistent store. The completion block will always be called on the main queue.
```

And this works fine for me, without any freezing.